# Entry Group Empty State

Tags: templating

I have entries that are getting grouped, but I've noticed that it will return nothing if there's nothing within a group. I'm looking to see if there's a possibility of showing an empty state to a user?

```
{% set loopCount = 0 %}
{% for status, proposals in proposalsByGroup %}
  {% if proposals|length %}
  {% set loopCount = loopCount + 1 %}
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-{{ loopCount }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-{{ status }}-tab">
    {{ status }}
      {% for proposal in proposals %}
          <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                {% include 'proposal/_proposalInfluencer.html' %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% else %}
    There's nothing here!
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, the above does nothing as no group actually exists so it won't run the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve an empty state for my group (When there's no entries existing within that group). I re-assembled the array and outputted them in a certain order - allowing for an `if` to come alive when there actually wasn't any status available.

```
{% set proposals = craft.entries.section('proposals').authorId(currentUser.id) %}
{% set proposalsByGroup = proposals|group('proposalStatus') %}

{% for status in ['pending','accepted','delivered'] %}

  {% if proposalsByGroup[status] is defined %}
    {% set entriesInStatus = proposalsByGroup[status] %}
          {{ status }}
          {% for proposal in entriesInStatus %}
             Hello.
          {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
          {{ status }}
          Nothing here, but still gives a status that you've set above.
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```